# Hibernate 5 and HBM Mapping issue, Schema-validation: missing table

Tags: java, xml, hibernate

I am taking an existing Java application and working on updating it from Hibernate 3 where we used hbm.xml files for Entity Mappings.   We are now using Hibernate 5.5.5.Final and the code compiles with ehcache, but now I get an error with the code when starting to run it.

I should start off that one of the Hibernate properties is:
validate

The error message I am getting now is:

```
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: missing table [my_db_dev.Project_myTemplateInfos]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaValidator.validateTable(AbstractSchemaValidator.java:121)
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.GroupedSchemaValidatorImpl.validateTables(GroupedSchemaValidatorImpl.java:42)
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaValidator.performValidation(AbstractSchemaValidator.java:89)
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaValidator.doValidation(AbstractSchemaValidator.java:68)
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:200)
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:81)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:327)
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:471)
```

I would love to completely remove all the hbm.xml files and replace with them with Entity Mapping POJO's with annotations, however, that is not an option right now.  The existing application has this different object model that goes throughout, so I don't want to mess with that right now.   That will be in the next phase.

According to the error I am missing a table named 'Project_myTemplateInfos' and there is no table with this name.  Instead, there is a table named 'Project' and the hbm.xml file for this is as follows.

```
<hibernate-mapping package="com.myApp.server.model">
    <class name="Project" table="project" dynamic-update="true">
        <id name="id" column="id">
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>
     <property name="name" not-null="true"/>
     <property name="displayCity" not-null="true"/>
     
     <list name="myTemplateInfos" cascade="all, delete-orphan" lazy="false" >
        <key column="projectId" not-null="false" />
        <list-index column="listIndex" />
            <composite-element class="com.myApp.server.model.MyTemplateInfo" >
                <property name="name"        not-null="false" />
                <property name="frequency"   not-null="false" />
            </composite-element>
       </list>

    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

As you can see 'myTemplateInfos' is a List within the Project table.  After the POJO is created, it looks like something like this.

```
@ModelBean(IProject.class)
@PermissionIdentifier("project")
public class Project extends ModelObject implements Serializable, IProject {

    private Long id;
    private String displayCity = "";
    private List<IMyTemplateInfo> myTemplateInfos = Lists.newArrayList();
    // getters and setters
    // hashcode and equals
}
```

Next we do have another table in the database that is called 'myTemplateInfos' and we do have an hbm xml file for that table as follows ... actually we do not have an hbm xml file for this, so maybe that is the issue.  I am going to create a hbm xml file for this and see if that solves the problem.

We do have a POJO for this object 'MyTemplateInfo' though.

If I simply remove his List from the hbm mapping and the Project object, the problem goes away of course, but there is another Set in the hbm.xml file which would give me the same problem, but with a new missing table.

The question becomes how to fix this error message.  Is the problem within the hbm xml file for 'Project', or is it in the Project POJO, or the fact that an hbm file does not exist for the 'MyTemplateInfo'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this was to fix the hbm xml mapping.   Since I haven't had to do this in over 15 years, I am very rusty with it.  I can't tell you how happy I was back then to switch to Java POJO's for Hibernate Entity classes with Annotations.   But now, unfortunately, I am back having to deal with these xml files again.

The table I had 'mycommunitytemplateinfos' I created a new hbm xml file for it as follows, and put this in the hibernate.cfg.xml file before the other hbm xml mapping.

```
<hibernate-mapping package="com.myapp.server.model">
    <class name="MyTemplateInfo" table="mytemplateinfos">
        <id name="id" column="projectId">
            <generator class="native"/>
        </id>
        <property name="name"        not-null="false" />
        <property name="frequency"   not-null="false" />
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

The mapping between this and the actual class is fine as I have tested this out.   I put the hbm file in the hibernate.cfg.xml file before the Project.hbm.xml file and modified the Project.hbm.xml with a one-to-many tag as follows:

```
<list name="myTemplateInfos" cascade="all, delete-orphan" lazy="false" >
    <key column="projectId" not-null="false" />
    <list-index column="listIndex" />
    <one-to-many class="com.myApp.server.model.MyTemplateInfo" />
</list>
```

And this seemed to work.   I had to do something like this a few times until I got the mapping right.    In this day of age, there isn't a lot of information about hbm xml files.   Hibernate 5 does use these, but I understand that the preferred way is annotated Java POJO's.    Unfortunately, I am stuck in a situation where I can't do that yet.